# Union of RDD IN SPARK

Tags: apache-spark

Here i am reading the data from kinesis and i am storing it in stream rdd.

Before i process that stream rdd i want the other bunch of data read from kinesis and do union with the previous rdd.

Like this i want to do union of rdd's for 4-5 times and then i want to process it further.

Below is my code

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<byte[]> stream = KinesisUtils.createStream(sc, "speng-batch-ss", "SparkStreaming",
    "https://kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", "us-west-2",
    InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON, Durations.seconds(batchIntervalSeconds),
    StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2(), ak, sk);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `stream.Window(duration * 4/5)`

Comment: What should be the duration? Because i want to know when the stream will finish reading completely from kinesis and when it will start reading the next bunch of data from kinesis.

Comment: Using Window the data will be overlapped. I want the distinct data.

Comment: Then you can set the slide to be equal to the window.

Comment: How do i create an Empty RDD and do union of Empty RDD with the stream ?